# I want to display form data in table and then table data gets stored in mysql and jsp?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, jsp

**Sorry for my bad English** 
i have HTML form in jsp contain three input fields:
Name,age,address. 
after filling form an submitting it should be display in HTML table
i have anyother button below table and its function is to store entire table data in mysql database.
first of all i thought about creating session in jsp and temporary table mysql to store table data and after user click on button it gets stored in permanent table.
Is anyone have any idea about how do i do this in JSP?

Comment: Yes there are many people that have an idea and get money for that

Comment: thanks for comment!

Comment: Oracle's [Java Enterprise 5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/) is the last EE tutorial that talks about JSP, it's a very high quality tutorial that should help you understand what you need to master and do to achieve your goal.

Comment: thanks for suggestion!